# Appending variable in for loop to mvc4 razor helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a number of fields in my model which are named as such model.var_1, model.var_2, ... model.var_30.

I am trying to put these in a table so I am using a for loop as so.

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Total; i++)
                {
                    <th class="ali_day@(i)">Day @i</th>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Intubated</th>
                <th></th>
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Total; i++)
                {
                <th>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.var_@(i))
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.var_@(i))</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
```

However, var_@(i) doesn't seem to be valid.  Is there a way to append this loop counter so I can get my variable name while using an html helper?

Comment: That is a poor design IMO. Would be better as something like `Days[i]`.

Comment: @TimS. I would agree, just thought I would provide a solution for what they had.

Comment: @TimS. Can you expand on why this is not good design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the editor helper overload that takes a string, that way you can use string concatenation to create the variable name.

```
@Html.Editor("var_" + i)
```

and the same for the validation message

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("var_" + i)
```

Comment: Many thanks that worked.  If you know what @TimS. was referring to by poor design could you elaborate more?

Comment: Basically if you are going to have 30 values with almost the same name and purpose you should use a collection instead of individual properties.

Comment: Any chance you have a link you could share that shows what you are talking about?  I could normalize the DB more a adding a model for days then have a one to many relationship but I don't think that is what you are talking about by using a collection.

Comment: I can't really find a link for what I'm thinking of, it's just one of those programming concepts that's common to all languages.  Perhaps @Tim S. can point you to something.